# Почему не срабатывает event.stopPropagation() после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: jquery

Есть блок, при клике на который отображается всплывающее окно. В этом блоке есть кнопка, при клике на которую отображается другое всплывающее окно. Для лучшего понимания я набросал простой пример - [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/e5REB/2/), в котором, конечно же, все работает хорошо.

Но в моем случае существует один непонятный "баг": после перезагрузки страницы я кликаю по внешнему блоку - всплывает окно, закрываю его, кликаю по кнопке внутри этого блока - всплывает окно для внешнего блока, закрывается и всплывает окно уже для кнопки. Дальше все работает как надо. То есть, после очередной загрузки страницы event.stopPropagation() почему-то не срабатывает в первый раз. Причем, интересный факт: если я перезагрузил страницу и сразу кликнул по кнопке внутри блока, то все сработало как надо, а вот при вызове сначала внешнего, а потом внутреннего события, возникает подобная проблема. Подскажите, в чем мой косяк?

Comment: всё нормально выглядит, наверное проблема не в этом. но я вообще бы писал

    $('.wrapper').on('click', '.button_wrapper span',function() {...

Comment: Если код написан правильно и ошибку не удается воспроизвести, то возможно дело в чем-то другом. Могу предположить глупый вариант, но мало ли - происходит кеширование с оптимизацией на стороне браузера, попробуйте поменять местами вызовы для создания обработчиков, может поможет.

Comment: @Alex Krass, пробовал - не помогает. Для всплывающего окна использую плагин, не знаю, может из-за него проблема? Весь код нет возможности привести, так как он достаточно большой, и при клике по блоку и кнопке происходит гораздо больше действий, но все они выполняются корректно. Может быть проблема не совсем понятна? Если говорить короче, то проблема следующая: при новой загрузки страницы метод stopPropagation() не срабатывает. Может быть дело в делегировании?

Comment: @andreyqin попробуйте повторить ошибку, без этого точно сказать нельзя. скорее всего проблема в разметке.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: Сам предположил и, кажется, сам исправил. Проблема, судя по всему, была в делегировании, правда, не совсем понимаю из-за чего именно (если кто сможет объяснить - буду благодарен). Решил просто: у кнопок, тех, что находится внутри блока, событие привязываю к каждой отдельно, т.е. вместо:
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'span', function(event) { /* ... */ }

пишу:

$('.wrapper span').on('click', function(event) { /* ... */ }

Но причину так и не могу понять.

Comment: ещё небольшое замечание

   alert($(this).get(0).nodeName);

не надо, хватит просто this.nodeName, т.к. this уже нода.

Comment: @eicto, это был просто пример, чтобы показать, по какому элементу происходит клик. А event.stopImmediatePropagation() я так же пробовал использовать.

Comment: @andreyqin, ну этот "просто пример", показывает как вы думаете :) вот я и говорю - так думать не надо. просто запомните и все  - this в коллбэках jQuery почти  всегда не jQuery объект.

Comment: @eicto, спасибо за замечание, я учту